# Find the matrix that represents a rotation clockwise around the origin by$ 30∘$ followed by a magnification by a factor of 4.

Tags: linear-algebra, transformation, transformational-geometry

Find the matrix that represents a rotation clockwise around the origin by 30∘ followed by a magnification by a factor of 4.

My attempt:

I multiplied the magnification matrix $\left[ {\begin{array}{cc}
   4 & 0 \\
  0 & 1 \\
  \end{array} } \right]$ by the rotation matrix of $-30$ degree, $\left[ {\begin{array}{cc}
   \cos(t) &-\sin(t) \\
  \sin(t) & \cos(t \\
  \end{array} } \right]$  where $t=\theta$.

Comment: Your approach is correct although the scaling matrix should be $[\{4,0\},\{0,4\}]$.

Answer (score 1):

The problem with this is that $[\{4\;0\};\{0\;1\}]$ is not a scaling matrix, it is a "stretching" matrix, only stretching vectors in the x direction. What you are looking for is $[\{4\;0\};\{0\;4\}]$. Upon multiplying these together, we get $[\{4\cos(-30^{\circ})\;\;-4\sin(-30^{\circ})\};\{4\sin(-30^{\circ})\;\;4\cos(-30^{\circ})\}]$, or $[\{2\sqrt{3}\;\;-2\};\{2\;\;2\sqrt{3}\}].$

Comment: This would be a 'stretching' matrix, although that isn't a proper name as such.

Comment: @rschwieb: You're right. My bad. Editing now.

Comment: (1) 4cos(30) = 2$\sqrt{3}$                                        
(2) -4sin(-30) = 2
(3) 4sin(-30) = -2 
(4) 4cos(-30) = 2$\sqrt{3}$

Comment: @AdamStaples: you're absolutely right. I've edited. Shouldn't do math when tired.

Comment: The correct answer is [{2sqrt(3),-2},{2,2sqrt(3)}]

Comment: @MeeraKapadia: Jesus, I'm bad at things. Thank you; edited.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do this is to find out where the standard basis vectors $\langle 1, 0 \rangle$ and $\langle 0, 1 \rangle$ map to.

In general, if we have a linear transformation $T:\mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2$ such that $T(\langle 1, 0 \rangle) = \langle a, b \rangle$ and $T(\langle 0, 1 \rangle) = \langle c, d \rangle$, then $T$ can be represented by the matrix $\displaystyle \begin{bmatrix}
       a & c          \\
       b & d \\
     \end{bmatrix}$.